# Problems with implementing System.Windows.Forms.Label into a class

Tags: c#, class, label, sharpdevelop

In my C# code, I am having trouble implementing a `System.Windows.Forms.Label` into my class. I am trying to achieve a label with a transparent background so I can put this on a transparent window to have 'floating' text.
Here is my code:

```
72|    public class floatingText : System.Windows.Forms.Label
73|    {
74|        this.Text = "Words go here";
75|        this.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
76|        this.ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
77|        this.BackColor = Color.Black;
78|        this.TransparencyKey = Color.Black;
79|    }
```

This code gives me the following compile errors:

```
74|    Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (CS1519)
74|    Invalid token 'this' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (CS1519)
75|    Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (CS1519)
75|    Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (CS1519)
76|    Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (CS1519)
76|    Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (CS1519)
77|    Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (CS1519)
77|    Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (CS1519)
78|    Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (CS1519)
78|    Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (CS1519)
```

I am new to C# and have absolutely no idea what is going on here, so if you could explain this in the simple terms, that would be much appreciated ;).
I am using SharpDevelop 4.3.3 and am running Windows XP Professional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the properties in a constructor like so:

```
public class floatingText : System.Windows.Forms.Label
{
    public floatingText()
    {
        this.Text = "Words go here";
        this.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
        this.ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
        this.BackColor = Color.Black;
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

Labels don't have a TransparencyKey so you may want to change the last line or did you mean to set this on the Form?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I was just gearing up to go for an in-depth Google search. Saved me some time ;)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be setting properties. You should be overriding them

For example, to override `Text`

```
public override string Text
{
    get
    {
        return "Words go here";
    }
    set
    {
        base.Text = value;
    }
}
```

For `TextAlgin`

```
public override System.Drawing.ContentAlignment TextAlign
{
    get
    {
        return System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
    }
    set
    {
        base.TextAlign = value;
    }
}
```

And so on... (You could remove the set if you don't want them to be changed)

Another work around will be to put those statements inside the constructor of your class.

Comment: @Levi Just remove the codes that are throwing the error and replace them with overriding properties

Comment: This method seems to work, but I am still having trouble overriding the TransparencyKey. I am trying to override it like this: "public override System.Drawing.Color TransparencyKey {". I have no idea what namespace/class TransparencyKey belongs to, but the MSDN says it belongs to System.Drawing.Color (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Never mind about that, @StevieB just pointed out that there is no TransparencyKey property for labels